# Flutter iOS text strings sharing between 2 Flutter applications

Tags: ios, dart, flutter

I have been looking for a way of sharing text strings between 2 Flutter apps I'm working on.
After days of research I was able to share a piece of text between the two apps using the `share` official plugin on the sharing app side and using Intent filter receiving text/plain for the **Android** platform. I have been trying to solve it on **iOS** since then.

There are 2 main problems

1. App A wants to share a piece of string data so app B has to show up in the options of receiving that data, here my app was not among the options.
2. If the data is shared with the app B, how will the app B handle the incoming data.

   I have already tried several options :

I. URLLauncher plugin official plugin couldn't open custom URL Scheme other than the web, sms stuffs,

II. The `share` plugin on iOS couldn't show my app among options of receiving text apps . I didn't find docs on how to make my app appear as a receiver of text shared by other apps and how to handle the incoming text in the receiver app.

Answer (score 0):

To show your iOS app in the options of where you want to share it, you can use the plugin [uni_links](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/uni_links) which works on both Android and iOS. You can define a custom scheme which then triggers your app.

Set everything up then create a listener:

```
import 'dart:async'; 
import 'dart:io'; 
import 'package:uni_links/uni_links.dart'; 

StreamSubscription _sub; 
Future<Null> initUniLinks() async { 
// Attach a listener to the stream 
_sub = getLinksStream().listen((String link) { 
// Parse the link and warn the user, if it is not correct 
}, onError: (err) { 
// Handle exception by warning the user their action did not succeed 
}); 
// NOTE: Don't forget to call 
_sub.cancel() in dispose() }
```

Comment: The docs are missing on how to launch the other app url scheme, only the listening and receiving part is mentioned.
App A wants to share data with app B, the part where the app A starts app B is missing in the docs, the docs only show how to handle or listen to the incoming data.

Comment: It is handled through the normal theme scheme. If you define the scheme to be `yourapp` and `name` then you call it with `yourapp://name`. This part might help you to understand it too: `android:scheme="https" android:host="[YOUR_HOST]"`.

Comment: I have been able to open it from other apps using the URLLauncher plugin, and also by specifying the receiving application in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes.